# Understanding Assembly Code for Binary Bomb

Tags: assembly, x86

I've been trying to understand some assembly code that was for a lab that I had to do in class and wanted to run my explanation by people that could point me in the right direction.
The code is as follows:

```
   0x080488bb <+0>:     push   %esi
   0x080488bc <+1>:     push   %ebx
   0x080488bd <+2>:     sub    $0x34,%esp
   0x080488c0 <+5>:     mov    $0x0,%esi
   0x080488c5 <+10>:    mov    $0x0,%ebx
   0x080488ca <+15>:    lea    0x1c(%esp,%ebx,4),%eax
   0x080488ce <+19>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x080488d2 <+23>:    movl   $0x8048c8d,(%esp)
   0x080488d9 <+30>:    call   0x80484e0 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>
   0x080488de <+35>:    test   %eax,%eax
   0x080488e0 <+37>:    jns    0x80488ee <phase_3_of_5+51>
   0x080488e2 <+39>:    movl   $0x3,(%esp)
   0x080488e9 <+46>:    call   0x80487c2 <explode>
   0x080488ee <+51>:    mov    0x1c(%esp,%ebx,4),%eax
   0x080488f2 <+55>:    add    %eax,%esi
   0x080488f4 <+57>:    add    $0x1,%ebx
   0x080488f7 <+60>:    cmp    $0x5,%ebx
   0x080488fa <+63>:    jne    0x80488ca <phase_3_of_5+15>
   0x080488fc <+65>:    cmp    $0x64,%esi
   0x080488ff <+68>:    je     0x804890d <phase_3_of_5+82>
   0x08048901 <+70>:    movl   $0x3,(%esp)
   0x08048908 <+77>:    call   0x80487c2 <explode>
   0x0804890d <+82>:    add    $0x34,%esp
   0x08048910 <+85>:    pop    %ebx
   0x08048911 <+86>:    pop    %esi
   0x08048912 <+87>:    ret
```

From what I gathered this function will take two inputs(from both the pushes). the __isoc99_scanf@plt will take a series of inputs saved as a string.

First part I'm confused about is the "test %eax,%eax" is this essentially comparing the value of eax with itself? I looked at a different thread in stack overflow with someone that had a similar question and one of the solutions said that %eax must be zero for the statement to be true.

If the above statement is true we move on to +51. +51 is saying that eax = esp+ebx*4 stored in 0x1c. Then we add eax+esi and store it in esi. Then we add 1 to ebx. We then compare 5 to ebx. If it's not equal it goes back to +15. If it is equal it moves onto +65 which compares 64 to esi. If they are equal the function ends.

Please let me know if my explanation is wrong, or if there is a part you feel you could clarify.

Edit: My primary goal is to figure out what I should input so that the program completes without calling the explode function.

I've narrowed it down to two inputs, ebx must be 5 to continue through one part. esi must be 64 to continue through the next part. The only issue I have is that esi relies on the value of eax, which I don't know.

4 and 48 are not the correct answers, any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test %eax,%eax` does a bitwise `and` of the `eax` register with itself. The only real effect of this operation is to set the CPU flags. The next instruction is `jns    0x80488ee <phase_3_of_5+51>`. That jumps to +51 *if the sign bit is not set* as a result of the previous `test` instruction.

Basically, if the high bit of `eax` is 0, then it takes the branch. If the high bit is 1, then it falls through.

Comment: So my input has no control over the test %eax, %eax statement. Would it ever call explode at +46?

Comment: Assuming the call to scanf is reading a 32-bit integer, then if the number input is negative the sign bit will be set. I think. You'll probably want to check the docs to confirm that.

Comment: Note that `eax` contains the return value from `scanf` which is not the converted value because that's written into memory according to the format string and the pointer passed in as argument. The returned value is the number of items processed or -1 on `EOF` or other error. This latter case is what the test in the code is looking at.

Answer (score 0):

`From what I gathered this function will take two inputs(from both the pushes)`

If you mean the first two lines, those are just saving the registers `esi` and `ebx` on the stack because the calling convention says they must be preserved. The code at the end will restore them. This has nothing to do with how many arguments this function takes, or how many numbers the `scanf` will process.

The `scanf` gets 2 arguments, the first is a format string which is at address `0x8048c8d` in memory. I guess if you check its value, you will see it's just a single `"%d"`. The second argument is the address of a local variable on the stack, this will receive the input number. (It's actually an element of an array, but that's not really important.)

The return value from `scanf` is then checked to see if `EOF` or an error occurred.

Line `+51` then loads the converted input number and adds it to `esi`, then increments `ebx` and loop backs to reading in another number if it's less than 5. What this means is, the code reads in five numbers one after another, and sums them up.

Finally, the sum is compared to `0x64` which is 100 in decimal.

TL;DR: you need to enter any 5 numbers whose sum is 100.